# RadioButton on DefaulTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton

How can I add a `JRadioButton` on my table with the help of `DefaultTableModel`?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Give more details, and what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 2):

In `DefaultTableModel`, you'll need to override [`getColumnClass()`](http://stwikipedia.org/doc/java_docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29) to return `JRadioButton.class`. You'll also need a custom cell renderer and editor, as discussed in the article [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).